# Custom ASP.NET Container Control Form

Tags: c#, asp.net

im fresh grad :D hehe. i want to make a container controller, when user choose the dropdownlist the container will be loaded, or the page will be loaded Example :
dropdownlist item : Category_form1, Category_form 2, Category_form 3

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategorySearch" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCategorySearch_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
```

and if the user choose Category_form2
Container will load Category_form2

.its hard to find a decent example of how to do this with ASP.NET.

Note : 
 - the dropdownlist category is not only 3 form, but actually i have 20++ more different form

Answer (score 0):

Instead use the MultiView control. It allows you to show one container at a time by setting the `ActiveViewIndex=1 or SetActiveView(view1)`

From the toolbox, add a MultiViewControl, inside the multiview markup, from the toolbox again add as many View control as you wish.
You can access each view with the index from 0,1,2.... and so on.
Add contents to the views just like normal div. 
When the user makes a selection then you can do something like

```
MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = cboList.SelectedIndex
```

Oh... Remember to set the ActiveViewIndex = 0 property of the MultiView1 control, it will be the default view when the page loads.